# how to redirect the from one activity to next activity with parameter

Tags: android, android-intent

I want that when a date is clicked, it will go to next activity. I included intent but it is not working. A null pointer error is thrown. I put this intent on different position in onclick function but it is not working and throws exception. Please help me how to get and go to next activity from this activity with date as parameter

```
package com.examples;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SimpleCalendarViewActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
    {
        private static final String tag = "SimpleCalendarViewActivity";

        private ImageView calendarToJournalButton;
        private Button selectedDayMonthYearButton;
        private Button currentMonth;
        private ImageView prevMonth;
        private ImageView nextMonth;
        private GridView calendarView;
        private GridCellAdapter adapter;
        private Calendar _calendar;
        private int month, year;
        private final DateFormat dateFormatter = new DateFormat();
        private static final String dateTemplate = "MMMM yyyy";

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.simple_calendar_view);

                _calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
                month = _calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
                year = _calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                Log.d(tag, "Calendar Instance:= " + "Month: " + month + " " + "Year: " + year);

                selectedDayMonthYearButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.selectedDayMonthYear);
                selectedDayMonthYearButton.setText("Selected: ");

                prevMonth = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.prevMonth);
                prevMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

                currentMonth = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.currentMonth);
                currentMonth.setText(dateFormatter.format(dateTemplate, _calendar.getTime()));

                nextMonth = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.nextMonth);
                nextMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

                calendarView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.calendar);

                // Initialised
                adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

        /**
         * 
         * @param month
         * @param year
         */
        private void setGridCellAdapterToDate(int month, int year)
            {
                adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year);
                _calendar.set(year, month - 1, _calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                currentMonth.setText(dateFormatter.format(dateTemplate, _calendar.getTime()));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (v == prevMonth)
                    {
                        if (month <= 1)
                            {
                                month = 12;
                                year--;
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                month--;
                            }
                        Log.d(tag, "Setting Prev Month in GridCellAdapter: " + "Month: " + month + " Year: " + year);
                        setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
                    }
                if (v == nextMonth)
                    {
                        if (month > 11)
                            {
                                month = 1;
                                year++;
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                month++;
                            }
                        Log.d(tag, "Setting Next Month in GridCellAdapter: " + "Month: " + month + " Year: " + year);
                        setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
                    }
            }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy()
            {
                Log.d(tag, "Destroying View ...");
                super.onDestroy();
            }

        // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Inner Class
        public class GridCellAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener
            {
                private static final String tag = "GridCellAdapter";
                private final Context _context;

                private final List<String> list;
                private static final int DAY_OFFSET = 1;
                private final String[] weekdays = new String[]{"Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"};
                private final String[] months = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
                private final int[] daysOfMonth = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
                private final int month, year;
                private int daysInMonth, prevMonthDays;
                private int currentDayOfMonth;
                private int currentWeekDay;
                private Button gridcell;
                private TextView num_events_per_day;
                private final HashMap eventsPerMonthMap;
                private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

                // Days in Current Month
                public GridCellAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, int month, int year)
                    {
                        super();
                        this._context = context;
                        this.list = new ArrayList<String>();
                        this.month = month;
                        this.year = year;

                        Log.d(tag, "==> Passed in Date FOR Month: " + month + " " + "Year: " + year);
                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        setCurrentDayOfMonth(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                        setCurrentWeekDay(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
                        Log.d(tag, "New Calendar:= " + calendar.getTime().toString());
                        Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfWeek :" + getCurrentWeekDay());
                        Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfMonth :" + getCurrentDayOfMonth());

                        // Print Month
                        printMonth(month, year);

                        // Find Number of Events
                        eventsPerMonthMap = findNumberOfEventsPerMonth(year, month);
                    }
                private String getMonthAsString(int i)
                    {
                        return months[i];
                    }

                private String getWeekDayAsString(int i)
                    {
                        return weekdays[i];
                    }

                private int getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(int i)
                    {
                        return daysOfMonth[i];
                    }

                public String getItem(int position)
                    {
                        return list.get(position);
                    }

                @Override
                public int getCount()
                    {
                        return list.size();
                    }

                /**
                 * Prints Month
                 * 
                 * @param mm
                 * @param yy
                 */
                private void printMonth(int mm, int yy)
                    {
                        Log.d(tag, "==> printMonth: mm: " + mm + " " + "yy: " + yy);
                        // The number of days to leave blank at
                        // the start of this month.
                        int trailingSpaces = 0;
                        int leadSpaces = 0;
                        int daysInPrevMonth = 0;
                        int prevMonth = 0;
                        int prevYear = 0;
                        int nextMonth = 0;
                        int nextYear = 0;

                        int currentMonth = mm - 1;
                        String currentMonthName = getMonthAsString(currentMonth);
                        daysInMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(currentMonth);

                        Log.d(tag, "Current Month: " + " " + currentMonthName + " having " + daysInMonth + " days.");

                        // Gregorian Calendar : MINUS 1, set to FIRST OF MONTH
                        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(yy, currentMonth, 1);
                        Log.d(tag, "Gregorian Calendar:= " + cal.getTime().toString());

                        if (currentMonth == 11)
                            {
                                prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
                                daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
                                nextMonth = 0;
                                prevYear = yy;
                                nextYear = yy + 1;
                                Log.d(tag, "*->PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:" + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
                            }
                        else if (currentMonth == 0)
                            {
                                prevMonth = 11;
                                prevYear = yy - 1;
                                nextYear = yy;
                                daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
                                nextMonth = 1;
                                Log.d(tag, "**--> PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:" + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
                                nextMonth = currentMonth + 1;
                                nextYear = yy;
                                prevYear = yy;
                                daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
                                Log.d(tag, "***---> PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:" + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
                            }

                        // Compute how much to leave before before the first day of the
                        // month.
                        // getDay() returns 0 for Sunday.
                        int currentWeekDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
                        trailingSpaces = currentWeekDay;

                        Log.d(tag, "Week Day:" + currentWeekDay + " is " + getWeekDayAsString(currentWeekDay));
                        Log.d(tag, "No. Trailing space to Add: " + trailingSpaces);
                        Log.d(tag, "No. of Days in Previous Month: " + daysInPrevMonth);

                        if (cal.isLeapYear(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)) && mm == 1)
                            {
                                ++daysInMonth;
                            }

                        // Trailing Month days
                        for (int i = 0; i < trailingSpaces; i++)
                            {
                                Log.d(tag, "PREV MONTH:= " + prevMonth + " => " + getMonthAsString(prevMonth) + " " + String.valueOf((daysInPrevMonth - trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET) + i));
                                list.add(String.valueOf((daysInPrevMonth - trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET) + i) + "-GREY" + "-" + getMonthAsString(prevMonth) + "-" + prevYear);
                            }

                        // Current Month Days
                        for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++)
                            {
                                Log.d(currentMonthName, String.valueOf(i) + " " + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + " " + yy);
                                if (i == getCurrentDayOfMonth())
                                    {
                                        list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-BLUE" + "-" + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
                                    }
                                else
                                    {
                                        list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-" + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
                                    }
                            }

                        // Leading Month days
                        for (int i = 0; i < list.size() % 7; i++)
                            {
                                Log.d(tag, "NEXT MONTH:= " + getMonthAsString(nextMonth));
                                list.add(String.valueOf(i + 1) + "-GREY" + "-" + getMonthAsString(nextMonth) + "-" + nextYear);
                            }
                    }
                /**
                 * NOTE: YOU NEED TO IMPLEMENT THIS PART Given the YEAR, MONTH, retrieve
                 * ALL entries from a SQLite database for that month. Iterate over the
                 * List of All entries, and get the dateCreated, which is converted into
                 * day.
                 * 
                 * @param year
                 * @param month
                 * @return
                 */
                private HashMap findNumberOfEventsPerMonth(int year, int month)
                    {
                        HashMap map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                        // DateFormat dateFormatter2 = new DateFormat();
                        //                      
                        // String day = dateFormatter2.format("dd", dateCreated).toString();
                        //
                        // if (map.containsKey(day))
                        // {
                        // Integer val = (Integer) map.get(day) + 1;
                        // map.put(day, val);
                        // }
                        // else
                        // {
                        // map.put(day, 1);
                        // }
                        return map;
                    }

                @Override
                public long getItemId(int position)
                    {
                        return position;
                    }

                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
                    {
                        View row = convertView;
                        if (row == null)
                            {
                                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_day_gridcell, parent, false);
                            }

                        // Get a reference to the Day gridcell
                        gridcell = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.calendar_day_gridcell);
                        gridcell.setOnClickListener(this);

                        // ACCOUNT FOR SPACING

                        Log.d(tag, "Current Day: " + getCurrentDayOfMonth());
                        String[] day_color = list.get(position).split("-");
                        String theday = day_color[0];
                        String themonth = day_color[2];
                        String theyear = day_color[3];
                        if ((!eventsPerMonthMap.isEmpty()) && (eventsPerMonthMap != null))
                            {
                                if (eventsPerMonthMap.containsKey(theday))
                                    {
                                        num_events_per_day = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.num_events_per_day);
                                        Integer numEvents = (Integer) eventsPerMonthMap.get(theday);
                                        num_events_per_day.setText(numEvents.toString());
                                    }
                            }

                        // Set the Day GridCell
                        gridcell.setText(theday);
                        gridcell.setTag(theday + "-" + themonth + "-" + theyear);
                        Log.d(tag, "Setting GridCell " + theday + "-" + themonth + "-" + theyear);

                        if (day_color[1].equals("GREY"))
                            {
                                gridcell.setTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                            }
                        if (day_color[1].equals("WHITE"))
                            {
                                gridcell.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            }
                        if (day_color[1].equals("BLUE"))
                            {
                                gridcell.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.static_text_color));
                            }
                        return row;
                    }
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                    {
                        String date_month_year = (String) view.getTag();
                        selectedDayMonthYearButton.setText("Selected: " + date_month_year);

                        try
                            {
                                Date parsedDate = dateFormatter.parse(date_month_year);
                                Log.d(tag, "Parsed Date: " + parsedDate.toString());

                                Intent intent = new Intent(SimpleCalendarViewActivity.this,ViewReport.class);
                                intent.putExtra("date",parsedDate);
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }
                        catch (ParseException e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                    }

                public int getCurrentDayOfMonth()
                    {
                        return currentDayOfMonth;
                    }

                private void setCurrentDayOfMonth(int currentDayOfMonth)
                    {
                        this.currentDayOfMonth = currentDayOfMonth;
                    }
                public void setCurrentWeekDay(int currentWeekDay)
                    {
                        this.currentWeekDay = currentWeekDay;
                    }
                public int getCurrentWeekDay()
                    {
                        return currentWeekDay;
                    }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Please, add logcat ouput

Comment: Post you logcat error

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried instead of:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SimpleCalendarViewActivity.this,ViewReport.class);     
intent.putExtra("date",parsedDate);
startActivity(intent);
```

This:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ViewReport.class);
intent.putExtra("date", parsedDate);
startActivity(intent);
```

Edit: Also don't forget to check your values, I just tested it both ways (xxx.this versus view.getContext(), with just parsing a new Date() which I later get via getSerializable, maybe your Date isn't parsed correctly?)

Answer (score 0):

maybe your value parsedDate is coming null, that's why this things occur. Please check that value and then call Intent.